# react.js : javascript in angle brackets not working

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

For some reason when I try and enter JavaScript into the angle part of the HTML portion it does not work. I'm using Thymeleaf.

Here's the HTML portion:

```
   <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.displayInfo}>Click for info about {firstName[i]}</button>
```

So in this instance it does not work and returns an error:

```
unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500) Exception parsing document
```

If I remove the `onClick={this.displayInfo}` it will work.

my function:

```
   displayInfo(){
        console.log("it worked");
    }

The render() function:
    render(){
        var {number, firstName, lastName} = this.state;
        var rows = [];
        for (var i in number)
        {
           rows[i] = (<tr>
                        <td>{number[i]}</td>
                        <td>{firstName[i]}</td>
                        <td>{lastName[i]}</td>
                        <td><button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.displayInfo()}>Click for info about {firstName[i]}</button></td>
                      </tr>);
        }
        var headers = <tr><th>Number</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Extra Info</th></tr>;
        return (<table className="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>{headers}</thead>
                                    <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
                                    </table>);
    }
```

Comment: *returns an error*, what's the error message?

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception parsing document.

Comment: What HTML template engine do you use? Or is it SPA?

Comment: I use Thymeleaf

Comment: @Wolfyaskingstuff please add `displayInfo` with class defination

Comment: I'm doing this in my render function

Comment: Could you share your render() implementation?

Comment: I added the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error because Thyemleaf thought that I was typing HTML:
I just added this:

```
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  ...
  /*]]>*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button className="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.displayInfo()}>Click for info about {firstName[i]}</button>
```

you should pass an arrow function in your onClick event