# react-dom: won't accept javascript inside the angular brackets

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf, react-dom

For some reason when I try and enter JavaScript into the angle part of the HTML portion it does not work. I'm using Thymeleaf, and react ver 15.0.0

Here's the HTML portion:

```
   <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.displayInfo}>Click for info about {firstName[i]}</button>
```

So in this instance it does not work and returns an error:

```
unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500) Exception parsing document
```

If I remove the `onClick={this.displayInfo}` it will work.

my function:

```
   displayInfo(){
        console.log("it worked");
    }

The render() function:
    render(){
        var {number, firstName, lastName} = this.state;
        var rows = [];
        for (var i in number)
        {
           rows[i] = (<tr>
                        <td>{number[i]}</td>
                        <td>{firstName[i]}</td>
                        <td>{lastName[i]}</td>
                        <td><button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.displayInfo}>Click for info about {firstName[i]}</button></td>
                      </tr>);
        }
        var headers = <tr><th>Number</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Extra Info</th></tr>;
        return (<table className="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>{headers}</thead>
                                    <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
                                    </table>);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any typos? It should be `onClick={this.displayInfo}` without parenthese

Comment: You're right, I changed it it no parentheses, as it should be but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Wolfyaskingstuff you already raise similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092729/react-js-javascript-in-angle-brackets-not-working

Comment: I don't know react, but the reason thymeleaf is throwing the error is because it's invalid html.    Thymeleaf expects attributes to be quoted like this: `onClick="{this.displayInfo}"`, so however you can get that to work with react.

Answer (score 1):

The `onClick` handler seems to be wrong.

```
const YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.displayInfo = this.displayInfo.bind(this)
  }

  displayInfo() {
    console.log('do your thing')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="btn btn-info"
        onClick={this.displayInfo}
      >
        Click for info about
      </button>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: I removed the parentheses from the handler but it still won't work.

Comment: Did you bind it in the constructor as well?

Comment: Yes, I did that as well. I used a class, though, and not a const.